# Solve for real numbers the following equation : $3x^{4}+x^{3}-10x^{2}-x+3=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Hello I need to solve the following equation without using substitution : $X=x-\frac{1}{x}$ :

$$3x^{4}+x^{3}-10x^{2}-x+3=0$$

If we take $X=x-\frac{1}{x}$ , then the equation is equivalent  to

$$3X^{2}+X-4=0$$

$$X=1,-\frac{4}{3}$$ Hence

$$x=\frac{1±\sqrt 5}{2},\frac{-2±\sqrt 13}{3}$$

But How to solve it using another method?

I think there is   trigonometric substitution.

Thanks!

Comment: What has your question to do with `calculus`? Or with `functional-equations`?

Comment: Could you include how $X=x-1/x$ gets you from the fourth degree starting to the quadratic? And what does "Mean:" refer to?

Comment: Have you tried factoring?

Comment: You could factor it to $(x^2 - x - 1) (3 x^2 + 4 x - 3)=0$ and then solve the two quadratic equations.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:Write your equation in the form $$\left(x^2-x-1\right) \left(3 x^2+4 x-3\right)=0$$ and solve then the equation!

Comment: Thanks sir @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner , but i think your factorization from here $1=x-\frac{1}{x}$ and the second $\frac{4}{3}=\frac{1}{x}-x$ , please if you know other method like trigonometry substation tell me ?